# spring data Elasticsearch reactive approach to update by query

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, reactive, spring-data-elasticsearch

Unable to find the appropriate approach to update by query (reactive) in sring-data-elasticsearch:3.1.1.

Earlier versions had something UpdateBy which took a query, but it seems to be deprecated in newer versions.

Looking for something to achieve this - [update-by-query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html)

I am not sure which method shall I use, the document couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.1.1 is a version from 2018, I assume you are not using that but mean that you use Spring Boot 3.1.1, the version of Spring Data Elasticsearch pulled in from that is 5.1.x

Since 4.2 there is the method `ReactiveElasticsearchOperations.updateByQuery(...)` check the [API docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ReactiveDocumentOperations.html#updateByQuery(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.UpdateQuery,org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.IndexCoordinates)). There is nothing deprecated here.